# Grpc deadlines and time zones causing deadlineExceeded

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

I am making a AsyncServerStreamingCall to a gRPC api hosted on the same machine as the calling application. I am specifying CallOptions within which I am providing a deadline.

The deadline is set like the below

```
new CallOptions(null, DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), DateTimeKind.Utc))
```

When running on a machine here in the UK it works fine every time, the moment my colleague in the US runs the code he will get a deadlineExceeded error immediately when the stream is opened. It I remove the deadline its absolutely fine.

Deadlines are obviously important and something I am keen to use. Has anyone experienced issues with deadlines and timezones? If so, what was the solution?

I add you cannot use DateTimeKind.Local as this is invalid for gRPC, it must be a DateTimeKind.Utc

Setting the host machines system datetime to UTC resolves the issue but this isn’t practical in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Wood for the trees moment, the issues is that the DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60) needed to be DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(60)

Comment: Correct, and then you do not need to specify the kind, because it is already UTC.